# MQTT publish / subscribe with Rest in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mqtt

I need to write an API, when client invoke that API it publish message on request topic of MQTT and wait for response on response topic. If response topic doesn't return anything then API should return default response.

My problem is while consuming message from topic. I am able to publish but how I can wait for response (to consuming message) for a specific topic and send it as response or after specific time send default response of API.

I am using Spring 4, Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement steps:

1. Your HTTP server receive a request and publish a request message with an unique correlation-id to MQTT, and create **event loop** E to wait message response
2. Consumer C1 consume the message and handle, then response (publish) a message with the same correlation-id to MQTT
3. Consumer C2 in your HTTP server consume the response message and give it to event loop E
4. Event loop E break a loop and return message response to HTTP client

Comment: Thank you Sann Tran for response, can you please point an any example that how I can use event loop in this particular use case.